# JPanel not showing image on the second time loading

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I am creating a project that pulls data from an SQL data base. While that data loads I want the end user to see a loading frame. On the first run it shows the frame with the image. The second time, when the user changes what zones he sees, the frame comes up again but this time doesn't show the image until after the function inside the action finishes. Could you take a look at my code and point me to what i am doing wrong?

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        ArrayList<String> newZones = new ArrayList<String>();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JFrame loadingFrame  = new JFrame();
            JPanel loadingPanel = new JPanel();

            loadingFrame.setSize(500, 500);
            JLabel loadingL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/gria/Desktop/Images/Loading.png"));
            loadingPanel.add(loadingL);
            loadingFrame.add(loadingPanel);

            loadingFrame.validate();
            loadingFrame.repaint();
            loadingFrame.pack();

            loadingFrame.setVisible(true);

// The Image will not show until this function finishes which is where all the data base connections take place. 
                Console.SetZones(newZones); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: 1) Probably because after the first time it never executes the code inside `if (LFrameCreated == false)` anymore, therefore it doesn't update the image. 2) Posting a [MCVE] will increase your chances of getting a good answer 3) It seems like there is an unnecessary over-use of static in your code. 4) Variable & method names should start with a lowercase letter (coding convention).

Comment: 1) if i take out the if and dispose of the frame it still give the same problem where it shows the frame but not the image. If I don't dispose the frame and take out the if it will show the image after all the data loads. 2) Almost every time i post here I always the a request for more code T_T

Comment: 2) I'm actually requesting *less* code. A [MCVE] should narrow down your code into one *compilable* example that only contains the really necessary lines to reproduce the problem. (Please actually read the page I linked to)

Comment: I did read thru and tried to shorten down the code a bit. I am not sure exactly what is causing the problem because it works the first time. If I remove the first time the loading frame is called it still calls blank the second time, inside the 3 block of posted code, so I am pretty sure that is where the problem is but I don't know how to recreate this problem with less code due to it having to do with loading a large amount of data.

Comment: I believe I have brought it down to a much more condense version of the problem. If you get the time do you mind taking a look again and seeing if you can find what I am doing wrong. Please and Thank you

Comment: I haven't simulated the `Console.SetZones(newZones);` yet, but maybe invoke it via `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`. I think this would ensure that the image was loaded before continuing: So replace `Console.SetZones(newZones);` with `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> Console.SetZones(newZones));`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks man not only for the help but also for the advice. If you put this as an answer I will get it marked correct for you.

Comment: Maybe it's better to accept copeg's answer. I forgot to mention background information such as the EDT and alternatives like Thread or SwingWorker. A SwingWorker is also useful if you want to implement a progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Image will not show until this function finishes which is where all the data base connections take place.

Swing is single threaded, which means calling any task that may take a significant amount of time will prevent Swing from performing its normal tasks (painting, event dispatching, etc...) until that task completes. Your code calls the following:

```
// The Image will not show until this function finishes which is where all the data base connections take place. 
Console.SetZones(newZones);
```

...from within an `ActionListener` implementation, which means it is being called on the Event Dispatch Thread (the EDT). To avoid this, call this method in a new [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) or use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Either way, be sure any calls to Swing from a different thread get dispatched to the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invoke*` or if using SwingWorker its methods

Answer (score 2):

To ensure the image was loaded before executing the database code, invoke `Console.SetZones(newZones);` inside [`EventQueue.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
EventQueue.invokeLa‌​ter(() -> Console.SetZones(new‌​Zones))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lukas Rotter posted the correct answer in his comment. The problem appears to be with

`(LFrameCreated == false)`

Comment: Taking it out, disposing the frame and recreating it causes the same problem.